# Wrong NSImage size?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am getting image size from a link on the internet. the image actual size is `630x420` , but when i print the image size i get `129x86` . (`image.size.width` and height )

When i log the `NSImage` , i can see there is pixels field with the right size, which different than 'size' field. so, why is that , and how do i get the pixels size ?

I know that in `UIImage`, the size is the actual size of an image .

```
<NSImage 0x600000260fc0 Size={129.59999999999999, 86.399999999999991} Reps=(
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x6000000b0b00 Size={129.59999999999999, 86.399999999999991} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=630x420 Alpha=NO Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x600000171c40"
```

Comment: Understand that the image on the net is *not* an NSImage, but a JPG or GIF or PNG or some such.  When the network image is loaded into an NSImage it is resized/cropped based on the "metadata" in the source file, plus any parms on the `imageWith..` constructor.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem and this helped me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , seems that with NSImage, size is not the actual size but relative to screen .

To get the real size :

```
NSImageRep *rep = [[image representations] objectAtIndex:0];
NSSize imageSize = NSMakeSize(rep.pixelsWide, rep.pixelsHigh);
```

Answer (score 8):

The size of an image in Cocoa, just like the size of most everything else, is measured in points. These are idealized coordinates that are assumed to be 1/72nd of an inch.

You may think that images are measured in pixels, and some are, but they can also have "real world", "physical" dimensions. An image has physical dimensions if its metadata describes the relationship between its pixels and some real world unit of length. A common way to express that relationship is DPI, dots per inch.

The image data you obtain from the net has a DPI stored in its metadata. It seems that it has a DPI of 350. 630 pixels at 350 DPI is 1.8 inches. 420 pixels at 350 DPI is 1.2 inches. So, the image is 1.8 inches x 1.2 inches in size.

Cocoa then expresses this in points. 1.8 inches * 72 DPI = 129.6. 1.2 inches * 72 DPI = 86.4. Those are the values you are getting from `NSImage`, within the ability of floating point numbers to represent them.

Cocoa is correct to consider this image as 129.6 points wide and 86.4 points high. If it didn't, then the image would draw at the wrong size on screen or when printing, given its DPI.

For the general case, you must also recognize that `NSImage` is a wrapper around image representations. An `NSImage` is just "a thing that can draw itself", not anything more specific than that. There may be multiple representations for any given image. Also, not all representations are bitmaps. Some may be vector graphics (e.g. PDF). Others may be procedural, using code to draw themselves. `NSBitmapImageRep` is the class which represents bitmap images.

Comment: Thats a great explanation that is not giving you any tool to actually get the image size. Sometimes seems that the knowledge is the main thing and not actually build and create new things . I would like to build a great creative album . and for that i need a 1 row code to get the size of an image like i do with UIImage . You could write 6 pages of documentation about image, but to be honest ,i am dealing with creating,building, not accumulating data about NS , that i am not interested in . Thank you. You have a great knowledge about the system .

Comment: From the [`-[UIImage size]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiimage_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImage/size) docs: "In iOS 4.0 and later, this value reflects the logical size of the image and is measured in points." So, it's just the same as for `NSImage`. The size of the image **is** 129.6x86.4 points. I was explaining the fact that the answer the framework gave you was the correct answer in the first place.

Comment: Looks like the OP just wants you to give them code to fix their immediate problem. Great answer though.